# Installing IIS5.0 on windows server 2008

Tags: asp-classic

Is it possible to install IIS5.0 in Windows server 2008 RT?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The version of IIS is fixed to the verision of windows server

- IIS5   Windows Server 2000
- IIS6   Windows Server 2003
- IIS7   Windows Server 2008
- IIS7.5 Windows Server 2008 R2